# Copy Sequential Files

Tags: shell, files, filenames, wildcards, cp

I have 12 files named `dmp_000`, `dmp_001`, etc, all the way to `dmp_011`. I would like to copy all of them to `rdmp_000`, `rdmp_001`, and so on, sequentially so the numbered files coincide. There must be an easy way to do this rather than individually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used this command to generate some sample data

```
% for  i in `seq 0 11`;do touch dmp_$(printf "%03d" $i);done

% ls
dmp_000  dmp_001  dmp_002  dmp_003  dmp_004  dmp_005  dmp_006  dmp_007  dmp_008  dmp_009  dmp_010  dmp_011
```

To duplicate the files and preserve the original files modify/create dates:

```
% for i in dmp*;do cp -p "$i" "r${i}";done

% ls
dmp_000  dmp_002  dmp_004  dmp_006  dmp_008  dmp_010  rdmp_000  rdmp_002  rdmp_004  rdmp_006  rdmp_008  rdmp_010
dmp_001  dmp_003  dmp_005  dmp_007  dmp_009  dmp_011  rdmp_001  rdmp_003  rdmp_005  rdmp_007  rdmp_009  rdmp_011
```

To move the files wdmp* to rdmp*

```
% for i in wdmp*;do newname=$(echo $i|sed 's/^w/r/'); mv "$i" "$newname";done
```

**NOTE**: You could also have used [@warl0ck's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/63046/7453) for that using the `rename` command.

Comment: In addition to that, what if I need copy wdmp_000, wdmp_001, etc to rdmp_000, rdmp_001? Where I have to rename the file itself? The duplication command adds the 'r' at the beginning, but I would like it to replace the 'w'.

Comment: Are you asking how to copy wdmp_000 to rdmp_000, but replace the r with a w? Use the unix command `mv` instead of `cp`. I'll add another example for that to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, that's works! warl0ck's doesn't work somehow. The fortran code doesn't read the new files.

Answer (score 3):

If the use of `zsh` is acceptable, then:

```
autoload -U zmv            # load zmv
zmv -C 'dmp_(*)' 'rdmp_$1' # rename files
```

Or simply in this case:

```
zmv -C 'dmp_*' 'r$f'
```

(`$1`, `$2` expand to the corresponding `(...)` groups and `$f` to the whole file path).

See [this link](http://www.drbunsen.org/zsh-file-renaming.html) for more examples.

Answer (score 2):

Posix compatible, short, and all your files can be referenced ( within the parens ) as positional params 1-12 if you want to expand on it.

```
% ( set -- wdmp0[0-1][0-9] ;\
> for f ; do cp $f r${f#?} ; done )
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this

```
for f in dmp_{000..011}; do [ -f $f ] && cp "$f" "r$f"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try rename command, and only rename those started with `dmp_`,

`rename dmp rdmp dmp_*`

To keep the files, try an alternate method like this,

`for x in dmp_*; do cp $x r$x; done`

Comment: Does that remove the original files? I would like to keep them, so rename won't work.

Comment: @GaryCai updated